# Storing signup form data to text file using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, backend

I need to store my data from signup form to text file how can I store? please help me to get output.

```
<?php
 //read data from form
     $activation_code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "activation_code");
 $first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "first_name");
 $last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "last_name");
 $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email");
 $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "phone");
 $concent = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "concent");
    //generate output for text file
     $output = <<< HERE

code: $activation_code 
 first name: $first_name
 last name: $last_name 
 email: $email
 phone: $phone 
 concent: $concent
 HERE;
 //open file for output
 $fp = fopen("data.txt", "a");
 //write to the file
 fwrite($fp, $output);
 fclose($fp);
 ?
```

How can I store data in a text file?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error with your heredoc syntax.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

There is a space infront of your closing HERE, which is not allowed.

Remove the space or just use double quotes:

```
//generate output for text file
     $output = <<< HERE

code: $activation_code 
 first name: $first_name
 last name: $last_name 
 email: $email
 phone: $phone 
 concent: $concent
HERE;
```

```
//generate output for text file
     $output = "

code: $activation_code 
 first name: $first_name
 last name: $last_name 
 email: $email
 phone: $phone 
 concent: $concent
";
```